# Batch file for changing proxy settings for chrome

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, batch-file, proxy

I constantly need to switch between auto-detect and a proxy server for my browsing needs. That's why I made a *.bat file to do the task for me. It is somewhat like this:

```
@Echo off
REG QUERY "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v "ProxyEnable" | Find "0x0"
if %errorlevel% == 1 goto turnoff
if %errorlevel% == 0 goto turnon
goto end

:turnoff
REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v "ProxyEnable" /t REG_DWORD /f /D 0
REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v "AutoDetect" /t REG_DWORD /f /D 1
goto end

:turnon
REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v "ProxyEnable" /t REG_DWORD /f /D 1
REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v "AutoDetect" /t REG_DWORD /f /D 0
goto end

:end
@exit
```

This changes the values in the registry. It works great for Internet Explorer. But for this to work in chrome, I need to open Internet Explorer, or I have to open Internet settings and click on ok.

How to make chrome automatically use the settings just like IE does?

PS: I also tried to open IE and kill it before @exit, but that doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think there is any difference between Chrome and IE because the setting is in the registry.

Comment: @KardiTeknomo, yes. But the chrome browser needs to be restated for the changes to take place.